# Flutter Web: RefreshIndicator not working anymore

Tags: flutter, dart, pull-to-refresh, overscroll

While RefreshIndicator was previously working fine on both, mobile and web, it doesn't refresh a screen on Flutter Web anymore. It's not possible to overscroll anymore on any of my screens, even if it's a long list, where it is easily possible on the mobile version.

I noticed the problem after updating from flutter 3.3.x to 3.7.9

[image]

Here is another simplified example. On phone it works well to reload the random generated numbers, on web nothing happens:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(const MyHomePage());

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String title = 'Hello';
  var rng = Random();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: () async => setState(() {
            title = 'Hey';
          }),
          child: ListView.builder(
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (_, i) => Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              color: Colors.lightBlue,
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 50,
              child: Text(
                rng.nextInt(100).toString(),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
              ),
            ),
            itemCount: 200,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to google for many hours, but didn't find any helpful information.
Any ideas?
Thank you

EDIT: Version by Niladri Raychaudhuri. Still the same problem
[image]

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version of the RefreshIndicator after upgrading to Flutter?

Comment: how do i do that? it's just part of the flutter/material.dart

Comment: Could you mention the class you are using. Provide the code in your post for better understanding. Also provide the error log, if any.

Comment: I edited the thread now with a simplified example. Nothing happens when trying to refresh on web, but it works on mobile. there is no error log.

Answer (score 7):

[Gif example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBbfz.gif)

I found a better way to fix that, it's simple!

Wrap your main content that receives refresh Indicator or list View with this

On behavior u can define scroll type with bouncing work perfect for me my content will back to up when end to push down

```
ScrollConfiguration(
              behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                dragDevices: {
                  PointerDeviceKind.touch,
                  PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
                  PointerDeviceKind.trackpad
                },
              ),
```

On your code

```
 return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(title),
    ),
    body: ScrollConfiguration(
      behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        dragDevices: {
          PointerDeviceKind.touch,
          PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
          PointerDeviceKind.trackpad
        },
      ),
      child: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () async => setState(() {
          title = 'Hey';
        }),
        child: ListView.builder(
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (_, i) => Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 50,
            child: Text(
              rng.nextInt(100).toString(),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
            ),
          ),
          itemCount: 200,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I tried that before, but it didn’t fix it for me

Comment: Try to change the physics in the ScrollConfiguratiion and in your listView

Comment: Works for me I will update my comment

Comment: working with flutter web 3.7.4. had the same issue as reported by OP. This solved my case.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2**

Added `PointerDeviceKind.trackpad` to set of PointerDeviceKind

**UPDATE:**

This is a known issue or maybe intended for Flutter Web and has been reported in Flutter Github

[Reported Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94677)

You need a custom scroll behaviour to override behavior methods and getters like dragDevices.

Follow the steps:

**1. Add plugin**

`custom_refresh_indicator: ^2.0.1`.

The solution should work with the native refreshIndicator as well.

**2. Write your custom scroll behaviour**

```
class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  // Override behavior methods and getters like dragDevices
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
        PointerDeviceKind.trackpad
        // etc.
      };
}
```

**3.Define your scroll controller**

```
 final ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
```

**4. Wrap your listView with a ScrollConfiguration widget and add your custom scroll behaviour to it**

```
child: ScrollConfiguration(
        behavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
        child: ListView.builder(
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (_, i) => Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 50,
            child: Text(
              rng.nextInt(100).toString(),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
            ),
          ),
          itemCount: 200,
        ),
      ),
```

**5. Finally wrap it with CustomRefreshIndicator or native RefreshIndicator**

```
CustomRefreshIndicator(
      builder: MaterialIndicatorDelegate(
        builder: (context, controller) {
          return const Icon(
            Icons.ac_unit,
            color: Colors.blue,
            size: 30,
          );
        },
      ),
      child: ScrollConfiguration(
        behavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
        child: ListView.builder(
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (_, i) => Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 50,
            child: Text(
              rng.nextInt(100).toString(),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
            ),
          ),
          itemCount: 200,
        ),
      ),
      onRefresh: () async => setState(
        () {
          title = 'Hey';
          print('Page is refreshed');
        },
      ),
    ),
```

**Final Note: I have used CustomRefreshIndicator here, you could use native RefreshIndicator**

**Full Code**

```
import 'package:custom_refresh_indicator/custom_refresh_indicator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(const MyHomePage());

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  // Override behavior methods and getters like dragDevices
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
        // etc.
      };
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String title = 'Hello';
  var rng = Random();
  final ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: CustomRefreshIndicator(
          builder: MaterialIndicatorDelegate(
            builder: (context, controller) {
              return const Icon(
                Icons.ac_unit,
                color: Colors.blue,
                size: 30,
              );
            },
          ),
          child: ScrollConfiguration(
            behavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
            child: ListView.builder(
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (_, i) => Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 50,
                child: Text(
                  rng.nextInt(100).toString(),
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                ),
              ),
              itemCount: 200,
            ),
          ),
          onRefresh: () async => setState(
            () {
              title = 'Hey';
              print('Page is refreshed');
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried these steps, but unfortunately it still doesn't work on flutter web, even if I use exactly your final code.
I added a new gif to the original post

Comment: Are you using a mouse or trackpad? Its working at my end though, try adding  PointerDeviceKind.trackpad to the dragDevices in MyCustomScrollBehavior.  
Note: The web drag is bit different here, try with a fast swipe on trackpad.

Comment: I am using the trackpad of a Macbook Pro M1, tried adding all options of PointerDeviceKind now. Even if I scroll from the top to the very bottom of the screen, it is not enough to reload it. One time I made it work somehow, with pushing the trackpad down so hard, but I cannot reproduce it again (I currently don't have a mouse to test it). With my old version of the app it is still easily possible, even with the trackpad. But with the new flutter version, I cannot get it to work.

Comment: I also tested it with mouse now, and I am still not able to refresh a page on flutter web with the current flutter version

Answer (score 0):

Workaround until the `RefreshIndicator` works again for Flutter Web:

Use a `scrollListener` and do this:

```dart
Future<void> _scrollListener() async {
  if (kIsWeb && _scrollController.position.pixels < -40) {
    _scrollController.animateTo(
      -500,
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    );
  }
}
```